# Browse Network UNC path

Tags: c#, networking, unc

I have a small form app that I wont to browse for network UNC path to then copy a folder im getting the error Cannot convert method group 'GetType' to non-delegate type 'System.Type'. Did you intend to invoke the method? on this code line Type type = oFolderBrowserDialog.GetType;

```
namespace Deploy
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        {
            FolderBrowserDialog objFolderDialog = new FolderBrowserDialog();
            textBox1.Text = GetNetworkFolders(objFolderDialog);
        }

            foreach (string dirPath in Directory.GetDirectories(textBox1.Text, "*",
            SearchOption.AllDirectories))
            Directory.CreateDirectory(dirPath.Replace(textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text));

        //Copy all the files & Replaces any files with the same name
        foreach (string newPath in Directory.GetFiles(textBox1.Text, "*.*",
            SearchOption.AllDirectories))
            File.Copy(newPath, newPath.Replace(textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text), true);
    }

    public static string GetNetworkFolders(FolderBrowserDialog oFolderBrowserDialog)
    {
        Type type = oFolderBrowserDialog.GetType;
        System.Reflection.FieldInfo fieldInfo = type.GetField("rootFolder", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
        fieldInfo.SetValue(oFolderBrowserDialog, (Environment.SpecialFolder)18);
        if (oFolderBrowserDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            return oFolderBrowserDialog.SelectedPath;
        }
        else
        {
            return "";
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change this line

```
   Type type = oFolderBrowserDialog.GetType();
                                         ^^^^^
```

Answer (score 0):

You are mising a set of `()`, just like the error message said.